# Kernel panic on MacBook 2009

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

Spam filter would not let me paste the error in my post so I've included a link as requested below.

https://nopaste.xyz/?7a089661db97f035#bpjQp6YUCI1++uC/cbEyxNREZJzE0ZBoY1emHCNDF7o=

```
Anonymous UUID: --- 
 Wed Nov 13 21:13:12 2019

*** Panic Report *** 
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801c4f43be): "thread_invoke: preemption_level 1, 
possible cause: blocking while holding a spinlock,
or within interrupt context"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.73.11/osfmk/kern/sched_prim.c:2068 Backtrace (CPU 0), 
Frame : Return Address 0xffffff802459af50 : 0xffffff801c4dab52 0xffffff802459afd0 : 0xffffff801c4f43be 0xffffff802459b060 : 0xffffff801c4f0e2f 0xffffff802459b0a0 : 0xffffff801c5c7bf0 0xffffff802459b110 : 0xffffff801ca8711c 0xffffff802459b140 : 0xffffff801ca8717f 0xffffff802459b160 : 0xffffff801ca8c900 0xffffff802459b180 : 0xffffff801ca8c93d 0xffffff802459b190 : 0xffffff7f9d25ce2d 0xffffff802459b220 : 0xffffff7f9d28b512 0xffffff802459b320 : 0xffffff7f9d20f614 0xffffff802459b380 : 0xffffff7f9d20cb2b 0xffffff802459b3e0 : 0xffffff7f9d25816b 0xffffff802459b430 : 0xffffff7f9d0bca66 0xffffff802459b470 : 0xffffff7f9d0bc795 0xffffff802459b4d0 : 0xffffff7f9d0bc9c8 0xffffff802459b510 : 0xffffff801c75da15 0xffffff802459b640 : 0xffffff801c838f5c 0xffffff802459b9e0 : 0xffffff801c84bc5b 0xffffff802459bae0 : 0xffffff801c84b20a 0xffffff802459bd20 : 0xffffff801c857813 0xffffff802459bd50 : 0xffffff801c9f1dbd 0xffffff802459be60 : 0xffffff801c9c672a 0xffffff802459bf00 : 0xffffff801c9c6493 0xffffff802459bf60 : 0xffffff801ca28341 0xffffff802459bfb0 : 0xffffff801c5ec3f6 
Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[848B398F-4D96-3024-8092-6CD3534D2CCA]@0xffffff7f9d0ab000->0xffffff7f9d0d7fff 
 com.realtek.driver.RtWlanU1827(1827.4b22)[B67310FB-8B35-3FF0-B628-98FC0E7A114F]@0xffffff7f9d202000->0xffffff7f9d4c7fff 
    dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[848B398F-4D96-3024-8092-6CD3534D2CCA]@0xffffff7f9d0ab000
    dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(900.4.1)[A0E77E09-5ABD-3E39-8453-CECBFC07C9DC]@0xffffff7f9d156000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He 

Mac OS version: 15G22010 
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 21 20:07:40 PDT 2018; root:xnu-3248.73.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 
Kernel UUID: 7564B0E7-EB5D-3887-BA79-59C870165AB1 
Kernel slide: 0x000000001c200000 
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801c400000 
__HIB text base: 0xffffff801c300000 
System model name: MacBookPro5,3 (Mac-F22587C8) 
System uptime in nanoseconds: 5626850922326 

last loaded kext at 245421936821: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f9efbb000, size 69632) 
last unloaded kext at 306122407546: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f9efbb000, size 61440) 
loaded kexts: com.realtek.driver.RtWlanU1827 1827.4.b22 
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70 
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0 
com.apple.driver.AGPM 110.22.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1 
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124 
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 274.12 
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 274.12 
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl 3.12.9 
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.6.1 
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 3.1 
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.13 
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 208 
com.apple.GeForceTesla 10.0.0 
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry 1 
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1 
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.4.6f4 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleHV 1 
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0 com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor 3.0.4d1 
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 245.4 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1 
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0 
com.apple.BootCache 38 
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4 
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController 327.6 
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1 
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.8.5 
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI 5.5.4 
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 3.1.8 
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0 
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI 1.0.1 
com.apple.nvenet 2.0.22 
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBOHCIPCI 1.0.1 
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8 
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 4.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1 
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 4.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7 
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0 
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 163 
com.apple.security.quarantine 3 
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8 
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 218.0.0 
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0 
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.12.9 
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12 
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 525 
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0 
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla 10.0.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.12.9 
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.14d1 
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7 
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP 2.2.6 
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.14d1 
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12 
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12 
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 204.4 
com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0 
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla 10.0.0 
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 108.3.2 
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11 
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.4.6f4 
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder 1 
com.apple.driver.corecapture 1.0.4 
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.4.1 
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.4.1 
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9 
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5 
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1 
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 900.4.1 
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.7.7 
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver 1.0.0 
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.7.7 
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub 1.0.1 
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc 5.0.0 
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0 
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily 4.6.1 
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0 
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0 
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.8.1 
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1 
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2 
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBOHCI 1.0.1 
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI 1.0.1 
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1 
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties 1.0.1 
com.apple.driver.NVSMU 2.2.9 
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0 
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1 
com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0 
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2 
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0 
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4 
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1 
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31 
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30 
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 4.0 
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9 
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4 
com.apple.kec.Libm 1 
com.apple.kec.pthread 1 
com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0 

Model: MacBookPro5,3, BootROM MBP53.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.8 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.48f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, PCIe, 512 MB 
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB Memory 
Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020 
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020 
Network Service: 802.11n WLAN Adapter, Ethernet, en1 
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB, 250.06 GB 
USB Device: USB Bus USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad 
USB Device: IR Receiver 
USB Device: USB Bus 
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus 
USB Device: 802.11n WLAN Adapter 
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus 
USB Device: Card Reader 
USB Device: 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub 
USB Device: USB Keykoard 
USB Device: Microsoft¬Æ 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0 Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: It's mentioning a kext for a Realtek driver of some sort, and Google Chrome. Get rid of both of those, and see if that helps.